# Eagle SPICE MOSFET Simulation Has the Wrong Operating Point

Tags: mosfet, eaglecad, spice

Having a lot of trouble getting an N-Channel MOSFET to work correctly in any spice program.  Trying something really simple to get started and I can't seem to get the MOSFET to "turn-on".  Am I missing something basic with how to simulation this type of circuit?  To be honest, I'm a little embarrassed I can't get this to work.

```
* SpiceNetList
* 
* Exported from Inverter.sch at 9/27/2020 7:28 PM
* 
* EAGLE Version 9.6.2 Copyright (c) 1988-2020 Autodesk, Inc.
* 
.TEMP=25.0

* --------- .OPTIONS ---------
.OPTIONS ABSTOL=1e-12 GMIN=1e-12 PIVREL=1e-3 ITL1=100 ITL2=50 PIVTOL=1e-13 RELTOL=1e-3 VNTOL=1e-6 CHGTOL=1e-15 ITL4=10 METHOD=TRAP SRCSTEPS=0 TRTOL=7 NODE

* --------- .PARAMS ---------

* --------- devices ---------
R_R1 N_2 N_3 100 
V_V1 N_1 0 10 
M_M1 N_2 N_4 0 0 NFET 
R_R3 0 N_4 80k 
V_V2 N_3 0 100V 
R_R2 N_4 N_1 80k 

* --------- models ---------

* (model found in library)

**********************
* Autodesk EAGLE - Spice Model File
* Date: 9/17/17
* basic nfet intrinsic model
**********************
.MODEL NFET NMOS (LEVEL=3)


* --------- simulation ---------
.control
set filetype=ascii
OP
write Inverter.sch.sim
.endc

.END
```

[image]

Comment: Your FET appears to be turned on and drawing 295uA. What are the parameter values of Eagle's 'basic nfet' level 3 model? Can you change it to a real FET with known characteristics?

Comment: A 5 V threshold voltage wasn't unreasonable back in the days when the defaults were decided for many SPICEs. Try driving the gate to 10 V and see if it turns on.

Comment: I raised the V1 voltage to 20V and got a similar result.  Should this circuit not have a drain current of ~1A given it's a 100V source and a 100 ohm resistive load?

Comment: LTspice shows extremely close results. This is a case of GIGO: garbage in, garbage out, because you're relying on the default model for the NMOS, instead of providing your own (or at least modify some parameters). That default model doesn't do what you think it does.